# Problem with vertical alignment of background image (background-position-y property)

Tags: css, background, vertical-alignment

I want to keep my background vertically-aligned (center) for all resolutions of screen. Always in the middle. So i use background-position-y property as "center".

Here is my css:

```
body {
background: url('https://i.ibb.co/5npL7fr/shutterstock-2179562083-bg-1024x576-small.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% auto;
background-position-y: center !important;
opacity: 1;
    }
```

But i see that my background is vertically on the top, not in center. What is wrong?

Here is jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/opfbn72v/

Comment: It's because the body is always the height of the elements within it and not the height of the viewport. Add height:100vh; (or min-height:100vh) to your body selector.

Comment: BTW if you want to position the background so it doesn't scroll with the content add background-attachment: fixed; too

Comment: Thanks for another good advice, just thought about it one minute ago

Comment: If we you don’t want to alter the height of body itself, put the background onto a before pseudo element and position that fixed. That also gets round the problem of background attached not working well on some versions of Safari.

Answer (score 0):

If You want make it center try with this CSS Code:

```
body {
        background: url('https://i.ibb.co/5npL7fr/shutterstock-2179562083-bg- 
        1024x576-small.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% auto;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        opacity: 1;
      }
```

And If you want to use background-position-y then you have to place the image inside the div tag and then you can use background-position-y center like:

```
        div {
              background: url('https://i.ibb.co/5npL7fr/shutterstock-2179562083- 
              bg-1024x576-small.png');
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              background-size: 100% auto;
              background-attachment: fixed;
              background-position-y: center;
              opacity: 1;
            }
```